# Generating HTML links in Laravel Blade

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

Alright, from the title says. I want to generate links in Laravel Blade. The catch, my content came from a Database.

```
Id |            Content                                              | Status
1  |  <a href="{{ asset('public/images/projects/p1_002728.jpg') }}"> |   A
```

My controller

```
public static function ViewPerProject()
{
    $data = Projects::GetProjectDetails();

    return view('works.project1', ['projectPackage' => $data]);
}
```

and my View

```
     @foreach($projectPackage as $project)
        {!! $project->Content !!}
      @endforeach
```

In which my link generates this when I inspect element.

```
<a href="{{ asset('public/images/projects/p1_002728.jpg') }}">
```

I want my link to generate the full path which is somewhat like this

```
<a href="localhost/arc/public/images/projects/p1_002728.jpg">
```

Any idea guys?

Comment: You should never need to use the word `public` when refering to a local resource. Try `asset("images/projects/p1_002728.jpg")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically storing a blade template inside of your database, which contains both Blade and PHP code. In order to display properly, this is a string that must be processed by the Blade templating engine, as well as the PHP engine.

There are two options.

First, you could dump the string from the database to a temporary file, and then use the `@include` directive to include your temporary file. This will obviously have a bit of overhead since you'll be performing a lot of disk I/O depending on how many records you're processing.

Second, you can call the Blade processing and the PHP processing manually. This will involve a call to `eval()`, but it isn't any more dangerous than writing the string out to a file and then including it (both of which are dangerous if `$project->Content` contains any type of user input!).

Your code for option two would look like:

```
@foreach($projectPackage as $project)
    {!! eval('?>'.Blade::compileString($project->Content) !!}
@endforeach
```

First, the `Blade::compileString()` method will take the string from your database and compile it from a blade template into standard HTML/PHP.

Second, the call to `eval()` will run your HTML/PHP through the PHP processor and return the resulting string. The blade template string processed by `eval()` must start with a `?>` to start `eval()` out in HTML mode, instead of PHP mode ([`eval()` docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)).

And third, the blade `{!! !!}` directives will print out that string without escaping anything.

Answer (score 1):

That's not gonna work. You cannot run php function in that way. It is like echo inside of echo.

```
    {{!! '<a href="{{ asset('images/projects/p1_002728.jpg') }}">' !!}
```

If you really want to save links to your database for some reason, why not save it like this:

```
<a href="[domain]public/images/projects/p1_002728.jpg">
```

This is similar a shortcode of Wordpress.

So before you display your data, you need to prepare it. Pass your data to your parser.

```
@foreach($projectPackage as $project)
    {!!  parseDomain($project->Content) !!}
@endforeach
```

And create a helper that will change the `[domain]` to your full domain or public path.

```
function parseDomain($content){
    $domain = asset('/');
    return str_replace('[domain]',$domain,$content);
}
```

But still, I hope you could just save the `images/projects/p1_002728.jpg` to your database instead of saving the whole element then echo it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try this:

```
<a href="{{url('images/projects/p1_002728.jpg')}}">
```

Answer (score -1):

The service should return this kind of array. just adjust the path to ./ or ../ as per you requirement.

```
public static function ViewPerProject()
    {
       $package = ['./images/projects/p1_002728.jpg','./images/projects/p1_002728.jpg']
       $this->data['projectPackage']  = $package;
       $this->data['someOtherData_1'] = [];
       $this->data['someOtherData_2'] = "test";

        return view('works.project1')->with('data',$this->data);
    }
```

In view you can use like this.

```
@foreach($projectPackage as $data['projectPackage'])
         <a href="{{$projectPackage}}"></a> 
@endforeach
```